# Pycharm navigation panel theme/color

Tags: pycharm

In Pycharm I have main theme = 'Warm Neon'. However Navigation panel shows up in black and white. I went through all menus and cannot find anything. Where can I select navigation panel to match main editor theme? Here is picture of my current set up.[image]